# Using jQuery on dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to jQuery and javascript. In my application I have a list of users. When a particular user is clicked from the list, a div element is replaced with details about the user dynamically. When another user is clicked, again I replace the same div element with this user details. So at a time only one user details can be seen.

I use jquery, so my code to the above description looks like.

`$('table#moderate_users tr').click(function() { 

$.get('/moderate/user/'+uid, function(data){
         $('div.user_info').html(data);

});

});`

This works perfect and the content is inserted dynamically.
I have a dropdown(html select tag) in the dynamically added content. So I get the dropdown only when i click on a user from the list and it changes repectively when I click on another user. I wanted to find the value of the select tag using jquery whenever it is changed. So I wrote

`$('select#assign_role').change(function(){

alert(this.val());

});`

Since this dropdown is added after document.ready, adding this script inside document.ready function never worked. I also tried to insert the above script along the with the user details which is dynamically added.For my surprise this script is not inserted into the document at all, while the rest of the HTML content are inserted perfect. I am not aware if i can add insert javascript after the document has loaded. I am not aware how i could use jQuery to find out the value of the select tag which is added dynamically. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want jQuery's "live" functionality:

```
$('select#assign_role').live('change',function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

also notice I changed `alert(this.val());` to `alert($(this).val());` considering that `this` inside a jQuery event handler references the actual dom element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: .live doesn't need to be inside document.ready, as it by definition works on things that still won't be there yet. Although, putting it inside the document.ready is a force of habit I have, so it can't hurt putting it there.

Comment: did you also change the alert clause as I suggested? Furthermore, can you inspect the select elment once it's dynamically inserted and guarantee that its id is "assign_role"?

Comment: Changing the alert clause like how you suggested, worked. Many thanks mike :)

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code, it seems that you are inserting a chunk of HTML into that div. So even if you wire your event to the dropdown after the page load, it will not work, since all of your event binding will be ignored when you insert new HTML code into div.
Try moving your code inside the function that inserts HTML. Something like this:

```
    $('table#moderate_users tr').click(function() { 
    $.get('/moderate/user/'+uid, function(data){
    $('div.user_info').html(data);
     $('select#assign_role').change(function(){
      alert(this.val());
     });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I tried moving into the function it doesnt help. .live function doesnt help too.

Answer (score 0):

On IE the live function doesn't work for onchange on `<select>` elements.

http://www.neeraj.name/blog/articles/882-how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery

You will need to either add the select then do a `setTimeout` and then bind with the `jquery.bind` type of functionality, or, what I have done, is when you create the element then just set the `onchange` event handler there directly.

If you don't need to support IE then the live function works great.